# Unity3D - Android Crash Because of Failed Setup Firebase Messaging SDK

Tags: java, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to setup Firebase Messaging SDK to my **Unity 2017.4** Project.

I choose **dot net 3** library to be installed.

Build is successfull, However when i try to launch apps then it crash.

By Log i get:

> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.snowyapps.belajarabc, PID: 4542
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.snowyapps.belajarabc/com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.snowyapps.belajarabc-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
>
> 12-02 16:40:57.237  4542  4542 E AndroidRuntime:   ... 9 more

any idea to solve this?

Thank You...

Comment: A couple of things to help find a solution:
1) is play services resolver enabled? Can you force it to run? See this article: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef
2) Are you on a device that has Google Play Services (ie: the Google Play Store?)
3) Do you have any postprocess hooks that might conflict with the play services resolver or build your game in non-standard ways?

It looks like you're missing a Jar/Aar archive, so I'm trying to figure out why Play Services Resolver may have failed.

Comment: @Pux0r3 at point 3, i build by export unity to android project then build AppBundle. for firebase analytics no problem but firebase messanger.

Comment: In that case, does it work if you do a normal build/run (rather than export). And are you using a mainTemplate.gradle (again, see the link I provided above)?

Answer (score 2):

Installing all the needed Firebase packages through the Package Manager instead of importing the `.unitypackage` files solved this for me. Some of my packages had been installed through the manager and some of them had been installed through importing, which apparently was causing some sort of dependency mess.

Go to your Package Manager (Window -> Package Manager) and search for Firebase. Make sure that the "All Packages" option is selected in the dropdown at the top-left. If any of the packages that you need is not marked as installed in the manager, install it.

If you get some error about GUID conflicts after reinstalling packages, just remove the conflicted files in the Assets folder and leave the Packages folder ones.

Comment: If someone can't find firebase in packages, you need to add the registry to manifest file, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup